# Mysql Merge 2 queries

Tags: mysql

I am trying to merge below queries in a single row such that results come in same row.
company_id is common in both queries.
Need Suggestion ???

1st Query:

```
select c.id as company_id,
    AVG(DATEDIFF(cdr.created_at,cd.send_to_brand_date)) 
        as Avg_time_taken_for_first_comment 
from 
    complaint3 c3,
    complaint3_details cd,
    complaint3_diary cdr,
    company c
where c3.id=cd.complaint_id
    and cd.send_to_brand=1
    and c.id=c3.company_id
    and cdr.complaint_id=c3.id
    and cdr.id in(
        select min(id) 
        from complaint3_diary 
        where complaint_id=c3.id 
            and user_id IN(
                select id from user3 
                where user_type=2))
    and c.id=351
    and c3.created_at>='2014-01-01'
    and c3.created_at<='2014-01-30'
    and cdr.created_at>='2014-01-01'
    and cdr.created_at<='2014-01-30'
```

2nd Query:

```
select c.id as company_id,
    avg(datediff(cs.created_at,cd.send_to_brand_date))  
        as avg_time_closure
from complaint3 c3,
    complaint3_status cs,
    complaint3_details cd,
    company c
where c3.id=cs.complaint_id
    and c3.id=cd.complaint_id
    and c.id=c3.company_id
    and cs.complaint_id=c3.id
    and cd.send_to_brand=1
    and cs.id IN(
        select max(id) 
        from complaint3_status 
        where complaint_id=c3.id 
            and status_type IN(2)
    )
    and cs.status_value=2
    and c.id=272
    and cs.created_at>='2014-01-01'
    and cs.created_at<='2014-01-30'
```

Comment: Write them as subqueries and `JOIN` them.

Comment: already tried using sub queries..but not working..0 results found

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM (<1st query>) AS q1
JOIN (<2nd query>) AS q2
ON q1.company_id = q2.company_id
```

Comment: already tried using sub queries..but not working..0 results found but individually both showing result

Comment: Do they have the same company IDs in both results? Can you make a sqlfiddle with sample data?

Answer (score 0):

You could use both Queryes as sub Query
SELECT (1st Query), (2nd Query) FROM << any table >>